# how to set header['content-type']='application/json' in ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, net-http

```
require 'net/http'

require 'rubygems'

require 'json'

url = URI.parse('http://www.xyxx/abc/pqr')

resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(url) # get_response takes an URI object

data = resp.body

puts data
```

this is my code in ruby, resp.data is giving me data in xml form.

rest api return xml data by default , and json if header content-type is application/json.

but i want data in json form.for this i have to set header['content-type']='application/json'.

but i do not know , how to set header with get_response method.to get json data.

Comment: thanks for  editing, and make it more clear. @rubylovely

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def post_test
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'
  @host = '23.23.xxx.xx'
  @port = '8080'
  @path = "/restxxx/abc/xyz"

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(@path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
  response = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port).start {|http| http.request(request) }

  puts "Response #{response.code} #{response.message}: #{response.body}"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use instance method [`Net::HTTP#get`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-get) to modify the header of a GET request.

```rb
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('http://www.xyxx/abc/pqr')
http = Net::HTTP.new url.host
resp = http.get("#{url.path}?#{url.query.to_s}", {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
data = resp.body
puts data
```

Comment: getting this error
C:\Ruby193>test1.rb
C:/Ruby193/test1.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
....query.to_s}", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
...                               ^
C:/Ruby193/test1.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
...tent-Type': 'application/json'})
...                               ^

Comment: @oecprashant Sorry, that's hash syntax error when typing code. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://www.xyxx/abc/pqr')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')

res = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).request(req)
```

Comment: I go this error on your last line : NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for #<Net::HTTP:0x007ff0bf8b47c0>: